# Unable to change re-change permission of a drive after changing it

Tags: windows-7, permissions

On Windows 7 pro, I changed a drive's (M:) permission using it's properties with a account which have administrator's (not Standard User) right for all "USERS" but it affected on my admin account too and I get "Access Denied" when I try to access the drive.

Now, I'm unable to change it again with the same admin account and I get "You don't have permission to view or edit this object's permission settings" error on Security tab of the drive's properties.
I also tried built-in "Administrator" account but I couldn't access again.

How can I change this drives permission again? is there any higher level user than "Administrators" I could use it?

Comment: There is no higher permission level higher then Administrator that you can use.  Its also not clear what you did exactly.  You should be able to take ownership as an Administrator.

Comment: Wow you right :D I fully forgot ownership and my problem solved. I'll be happy if you write this as Answer.

Comment: Feel free to answer the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound) said, I should take the ownership of drive and after a simple restart, I was able to change the permissions again.